# Angular - Can we subscribe only to the first time that a BehaviorSubject is modified?

Tags: angular, behaviorsubject

I have a service, and there I am using `BehaviorSubject` to control the changes made to any user:

```
  private usersList: User|undefined = undefined;
  private _usersList: BehaviorSubject<User|undefined> = new BehaviorSubject<User|undefined>(undefined);
  private _usersList$ = this._usersList.asObservable();
```

I also have a function that I am listening to in a different component, to know whenever there is a change in the users list:

```
  onUsersChange(): Observable<User|undefined> {
    return this._usersList$;
  }
```

My question is, is there a way I can listen only to the first time that the observable is fired or listen to the first time only, that my `_userList` is modified?

Answer (score 0):

have you tried `first()`?

```
onUsersChange(): Observable<User|undefined> {
    return this._usersList$.pipe(first());
}
```

Supposing you also want to ignore an undefined first value, you can also use `filter` to make sure that you are not intercepting an undefined emission:

```
onUsersChange(): Observable<User|undefined> {
    return this._usersList$.pipe(
        first(),
        filter( user => user != undefined)
    );
}
```

Comment: I believe this is to take the first data that I would receive. I meant to know when is the first time that there is a change on the data.

Comment: this Observable will be fired only once so clearly when it's fired you know that this is the first time. if you only want to know that it's fired simply set a veriable outside called `isFired = false` then from `tap` operator inside observable stream set it to true, then you'll know it was fired

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you need to try first() or take(). It depends on your need which one to prefer from

> The difference is when there are no elements in the input stream. In
> this case, first() throws an Error, while take(1) closes the
> Observable without any elements.

This is an excellent article on the same. I hope this helps :)
https://advancedweb.hu/rxjs-the-differences-between-first-take-1-and-single/

Comment: I believe this is to take the first data that I would receive. I meant to know when is the first time that there is a change on the data.

Comment: so you only want to be notified and not use the data

Comment: I will use the data anyways, but I want to do something if it is the first time being modified

Comment: you can write function call inside first operator. try that

Answer (score 0):

You can use `take` from rxjs, just like that:

```
onFirstUsersChange$(): Observable<User | undefined> {
   return this.onUsersChange().pipe(take(1));
}
```

Supposing you also want to ignore an undefined first value, you can also use `filter` to make sure that you are not intercepting an undefined emission:

```
onUsersChange(): Observable<User|undefined> {
    return this._usersList$.pipe(
        filter( user => user != undefined),
        take(1)
    );
}
```

Comment: I believe this is to take the first data that I would receive. I meant to know when is the first time that there is a change on the data.

Comment: So what you want is to skip the initial value assigned to the `BehaviourSubject`?

Comment: I want to know when it is the first time that the BehaviorSubject value is changing.

Comment: If you are not interested in the first value emitted by the observable, which is the initial value you provided in the `BehaviourSubject` constructor, consider turning your `BehaviourSubject` into a `Subject` when initializing it. Otherwise, you can use the `skip(1)` from rxjs. Anyways, consider trying to see the problem from a publish-and-subscribe POV other than "the current value of this variable", I think it's a more suitable approach to Angular and rxjs logics :)